# Forward, redirect, forward!! How do I check parameters being sent?

Tags: forms, parameters

There's this form that I'm placing on a site. This form submits some parameters to a site which then sends some parameters using "GET" to another site, which then opens the third site.

Now the first 2 sites pass so quickly that I can not see what parameters were passed using the URL.

I just need a simple tool or hint or firefox addon or ANYTHING ELSE on how to track what parameters were sent to url1, url2 etc.

There's got to be some tool for this, only I can't seem to find it! Argh!

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

And of course Firebug extension (Firefox). Use the Net panel to monitor requests

Answer (score 0):

I'd break out the packet sniffer; try WireShark or snort. It won't work for HTTPS, though...

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) for firefox..